# Apply operators (+, -, *, /) to Eastern Arabic numbers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, operators, arabic

Many answers has been found how to convert Eastern Arabic number (`٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨`) to  Western Arabic number (`01234567`) & vise versa.

However, is there a way to apply **mathematical operators** on Eastern Arabic numbers .
I am looking for something like following :

```
'١٢٣'+'١١٢'==235
'١٢٣'-'١١٢'==-11
'٢'*'٣'==6
 '١'==='٢'   //false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extends `Number` class & override `valueOf` method (Solution based on ES6)

```js
class EANum extends Number{
     constructor(){
         super();
         this.value=arguments[0];
     }
    valueOf(){
       return  Number( this.value.replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g,(d)=> d.charCodeAt(0) - 1632).replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, (d)=> d.charCodeAt(0) - 1776));
    }
    toString(){
       return this.valueOf();
    }

}

var a=new EANum('٣٤'),b=new EANum('١١');
console.log(a); // 
console.log(a+b); //45
console.log(a-b); //23
console.log(a*b); //374
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! clever solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this simple method. However, it would be subject to untrusted code injection if there's no control over the input.

```js
function evalArabic(expr) {
  var fn = new Function(
    'return (' + expr.replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, function(c) {
      return c.charCodeAt(0) - 0x660;
    }) + ')'
  );  
  return fn();
}

console.log(evalArabic('١٢٣ + ١١٢'));
console.log(evalArabic('١٢٣ - ١١٢'));
console.log(evalArabic('٢ * ٣'));
console.log(evalArabic('١ === ٢'));

// this one is bad:
// console.log(evalArabic('alert("p4wn3d! lol")'));
```